# What are the best ways to insert blank lines in logs using python logging?

Tags: python, logging

I currently do

```
# three extra blank lines per srh for debug log
logging.info('')
logging.info('')
logging.info('')
```

But this makes the code bloated, is there any better way?

Comment: `"\n\n\n"`? Why do you need blank lines?

Comment: Use a loop in a helper function?

Answer (score 4):

It's not really a blank line, but sometimes I use this:

```
logging.info('-' * 80)
```